# Why in George Pal's film "The time machine" a sudden stop of the machine causes a rain?

Tags: time-travel, h.g.wells

in [George Pal's film "The Time Machine"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine_(1960_film)), based on the [novella by H.G. Wells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Time_Machine), there is a scene in which the protagonist stops his machine abruptly after having been travelling towards the future at great speed. When he stops his machine, it begins to spin on itself, the protagonist falls from it and a sudden rain is unleashed on him whose cause, I deduce, is that sudden stop.

[image: Twisting Time Machine]

Could you give me an explanation of the scientific (or fantastic-scientific) principles that would cause this rain?

Any response based on other means (e.g., the original book) will be welcome. I read the book many years ago and don't remember one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is addressed in the film's [screenplay](https://sfy.ru/?script=time_machine_1960). In short, the machine's abrupt arrival forced the misty air to condense into hail.

> [As he eagerly pulls hard on the lever, the HUMMING
>   DECREASES and the dial freezes on:  "23 November
>   802,701".  THERE IS A CRASH LIKE THUNDER and the
>   Time Machine suddenly goes into a spin.  The CAMERA
>   ZOOMS BACK TO A FULL HIGH SHOT as the machine keels
>   over.  **The friction caused by the intrusion creates
>   a pitiless HAIL**, and we]
>
> SLOWLY DISSOLVE TO:
>
> Thick mist eddies about his face, undulating
>   dreamily, revealing enough to see that he is
>   unconscious.  Blood seeps from a gash across his
>   forehead.  He dazedly opens his eyes to find that
>   he is gazing across the dewey, green turf.  Then
>   he looks up.

which in turn is pretty faithful to the Wells' [original text](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/35/35-h/35-h.htm#chap04).

> *The fact is that, insensibly, the absolute strangeness of everything,
>   the sickly jarring and swaying of the machine, above all, the feeling
>   of prolonged falling, had absolutely upset my nerves. I told myself
>   that I could never stop, and with a gust of petulance I resolved to
>   stop forthwith. Like an impatient fool, I lugged over the lever, and
>   incontinently the thing went reeling over, and I was flung headlong
>   through the air.*
>
> ***“There was the sound of a clap of thunder in my ears. I may have been
>   stunned for a moment. A pitiless hail was hissing round me, and I was
>   sitting on soft turf in front of the overset machine. Everything still
>   seemed grey, but presently I remarked that the confusion in my ears
>   was gone. I looked round me. I was on what seemed to be a little lawn
>   in a garden, surrounded by rhododendron bushes, and I noticed that
>   their mauve and purple blossoms were dropping in a shower under the
>   beating of the hailstones. The rebounding, dancing hail hung in a
>   little cloud over the machine, and drove along the ground like smoke.
>   In a moment I was wet to the skin. ‘Fine hospitality,’ said I, ‘to a
>   man who has travelled innumerable years to see you.’***
>
> *“Presently I thought what a fool I was to get wet. I stood up and
>   looked round me. A colossal figure, carved apparently in some white
>   stone, loomed indistinctly beyond the rhododendrons through the hazy
>   downpour. But all else of the world was invisible.*
>
> *“My sensations would be hard to describe. As the columns of hail grew
>   thinner, I saw the white figure more distinctly. It was very large,
>   for a silver birch-tree touched its shoulder. It was of white marble,
>   in shape something like a winged sphinx, but the wings, instead of
>   being carried vertically at the sides, were spread so that it seemed
>   to hover. The pedestal, it appeared to me, was of bronze, and was
>   thick with verdigris. It chanced that the face was towards me; the
>   sightless eyes seemed to watch me; there was the faint shadow of a
>   smile on the lips. It was greatly weather-worn, and that imparted an
>   unpleasant suggestion of disease. I stood looking at it for a little
>   space—half a minute, perhaps, or half an hour. It seemed to advance
>   and to recede as the hail drove before it denser or thinner. At last I
>   tore my eyes from it for a moment, and saw that the hail curtain had
>   worn threadbare, and that the sky was lightening with the promise of
>   the sun.*

In neither case is there any good *scientific* explanation for this phenomenon in evidence.

Comment: There may be an explanation. Mist is not water vapor; it's an aerosol, in particular water droplets suspended in the air. Liquids below the critical temperature (freezing point) can nucleate around impurities if disturbed, causing a liquid-solid transition. I haven't heard of this happening with mist, but it does happen with liquid water, including raindrops.

Comment: @Adamant - Sure, but an object arriving would create overpressure, surely.

Comment: Yes, but what matters for supercritical nucleation is that it will apply a force to the droplets (an outward pressure wave, as you seem to be saying). Like shaking a bottle of cold water. I'm sure the hail is unrealistically large, and the temperature is probably too high, but the principle might work.

Comment: Anyway, it certainly looks as if in the short story it's just weather of some sort.